# Unclear network topology ( bizarre host up )

Tags: networking, home-networking, nmap

I am new to networking, so please have mercy :)

Right now I'm at home and I tryied to scan my network with nmap.

I've done two simple scans:

`nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24`

which gives me the devices connected to my router (laptop, phone...) as expected, and :

`nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24`

which reports a living host, in this case 192.168.1.3

`ifconfig` gives me:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 PRIVATE  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 118374  bytes 93573769 (89.2 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 288245  bytes 73758072 (70.3 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My (modem/)router is at 192.168.0.1, so why do I have a live IP at 192.168.1.3 ?

How can this happen ? Which is the position of this IP compared to my home network ? Which kind of device this could be ?

Please let me know if you need more infos. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the nmap output returned from that 192.168.1.3 host please. That alone could contain enough info to identify the device. 192.168.1.* is outside your normal network range, that is true, but nmap is designed to gather as much info as possible even though this ip-address wouldn't make sense normally.

Comment: I scanned the address and I got nothing about his OS or services versions as all port are filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in *your* network. Nmap doesn't always do a local scan: if you give it an address that's outside your subnet, it will follow regular routing table rules and go through a gateway.

So you might very well have reached another LAN somewhere *beyond* your router.

It's possible that the address is used by your ISP. For example, many ISPs use a separate "device management" network, in which case your router might have a LAN address, an Internet address, *and* a management address.

(If your router and modem are separate, then it might be a management address of your modem. You might even be reaching the ISP's own systems somewhere further away. Yes, the ISP is *supposed to* secure their own stuff... but that doesn't always happen.)

Or the router might be using 192.168.1.0/24 as a local subnet for guest Wi-Fi, or IPTV, or such.

To get more details about where the path leads, you can check:

- The computer's and the router's *routing tables* – see if it has any entries for 192.168.1 (or shorter prefix). On Linux use `ip -4 route`, on Windows `route -4 print`.
- `traceroute` or `tracert` will show you the entire path (i.e. all routers traversed).
- If traceroute doesn't work, try `ping -R` (record route), which provides similar output.

---

To scan a mismatching subnet *locally*, you will need to use `nmap -PR -sn 192.168.1.0/24` instead – this doesn't do a portscan, only checks whether any of the addresses are alive.

Since this type of scan (using ARP) is always local, it'll also report MAC addresses of every found device, which you can use to look up the device manufacturer.

Comment: Nice! Effectively if I do `nmap -PR -sn 192.168.1.0/24` no host is up.

Comment: It's an IP of a LAN beyond my router. A traceroute proof that. I didn't get very well what's a management address, I'll dig that. Thanks!